# Azure Key Vault dependency error while deploying to Azure App Service

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

When I deployed the app to Azure, I get HTTP ERROR 500. But local setup works fine as excepted.

Log file message below while accessing the Azure endpoint:

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'TestDB' on server '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'ItemApp.Infrastructure.Repository.ItemDBContext'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: SNI_PN11, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

I installed SQL Server Express with Localdb option since it said "Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation" but still getting same error. I am able to deploy the same app to Azure successfully and hit endpoints if I remove Azure Key vault from the code.

Below is my code for Azure Key Vault:

Connection String is stored in Azure Key Vault as below:

```
    Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=TestDB; Trusted_Connection=True
```

appsettings.json file:

```
// AzureAD setting for Authentication
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "Audience": "",
    "Issuer": "",
    "ClientSecret": ""

},

//Key Vault setting
"VaultConfig": {
    "VUrl": ""
}
```

Program.cs file:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })

         // calls Azure Key Vault with values supplied by the appsettings.json file
         .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
         {
             var builtConfig = config.Build();
             string vUrl = builtConfig["VaultConfig:VUrl"];
             string tenantId = builtConfig["AzureAd:TenantId"]; 
             string clientId = builtConfig["AzureAd:ClientId"];
             string clientSecret = builtConfig["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
             var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
             var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(vUrl), credential);
             config.AddAzureKeyVault(client, new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions());
         });

}
```

Startup.cs code:

```
 // "DevConnection" is the key we have used to store database Connection String. 
        services.AddDbContext<ItemDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection"),
        optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly("ItemApp.Infrastructure")
        ));
```

May I know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the web api you are trying to fetch the connection string from the key vault for accessing the SQL DB, if I'm not wrong. Can you check whether the **web api managed identity or the service principal is added to the key vault access control**.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am trying to access database connection string. Yes service principal is added to key vault access control. I have not configured for managed identity. My doubt is if program.cs file has trouble accessing Azure AD credentials (App credentials) while running Key Vault code. But the same setup works perfectly in local (So I am struck where the problem is). Also works when deployed to Azure without Key Vault (there was no problem accessing azure credentials from appsettings file).

Comment: Hi, do you think I need to configure for managed identity separately. When I click Identity tab on my App Service, system assigned managed identity status is ON by default.

Comment: Yes, you can try configuring the user assigned managed identity and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve by changing the connection string to point to Azure database instead of localdb.